# Список зануляется каждый раз после вызова функции изменяещей его

Tags: python

Вот такой код

```
import random
field = ([0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0])
random.seed()

def pt():
    count = 0
    while count != 1:
        x = random.randint(0, 3)
        y = random.randint(0, 3)
        z = random.randint(0, 100)
        if field[x][y] != 0:
            if z <= 10: field[x][y] = 4
            if z > 10: field[x][y] = 2
            count+=1
            print field
```

вот вывод если несколько раз вызвать функцию

```
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
([0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0])
```

Как будто лист зануляется каждый раз. Как исправить это?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что в условии

```
if field[x][y] != 0:
```

надо проверять на равенство, из за этого создалось впечатление что он зануляется.